# Visual Studio Team Explorer Extension

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer

I am trying to create an extension for Team Explorer window in VS2017.
I want to put another button on the changes screen, or even hook into the commit method, so that I can take the comments, and integrate with a Kanbanize board.
It seems like it should be possible to but a button onto the Team Explorer window, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation I can find, or examples.
I have looked around and can only really find this link below, which I tried but doesn't seem to work, but isn't really what I am wanting to do.

https://hamidshahid.blogspot.com/2017/09/extending-team-explorer-in-vs2017.html

Answer (score 0):

The Team Explorer extensibility is designed to enable adding new sections to an existing page, but altering the existing sections to change their UI/behavior is not allowed.  Given this design constraint, you can add your own UI, but it'll need to be in a separate section.  You should be able to read the selection data from other sections on the Git Changes page via [IChangesExt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/dn358547%28v%3Dvs.120%29).

Hope this helps.